# Getting the string at a certain index using a variable

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm not sure why this isn't working. I'm trying to print out whats inside of a specific index of a string array. Every time I get an `undefined`.

My JavaScript

```js
const { log: $, warn: $w, error: $e } = console;
const btn = document.querySelector(".click");
const app = document.querySelector(".app2");
let pressed = 0;
let titleArray = [];

btn.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  pressed++;
  titleArray.push(`Button pressed ${pressed}`);
  $(getArrayString(pressed));
  app.innerHTML += `
  <h1 class="title">Button pressed ${pressed}</h1>
`;
});

function getArrayString(pressed) {
  return titleArray[pressed];
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="app">
  <h1 class="newtitle">Click this button</h1>
  <button class="click">Click me</button>
</div>

<div class="app2"></div>
```

Just to make sure I'm not doing anything very wrong I've tried doing it this way and they all work.

```js
  const testNumb = 0;
  $(titleArray[0]);
```

```js
  $(titleArray[0]);
```

```js
  $(getArrayString());
//returns undefined until it the array gets big enough then it prints whatever is stored in index

function getArrayString() {
  return titleArray.toString();
}
```

Comment: Arrays are 0-indexed. `$(getArrayString(pressed - 1));` should work. Voting to close as a typo/no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array indexes start at `0`, but you're incrementing `pressed` before you push into the array.

So the first time you click, you set `pressed` to `1`, then push `Button pressed 1` into the array, but it's at index `0`. When you use `getArrayString(pressed)`, it tries to read `titleArray[1]`, which isn't filled in yet, so you get `undefined`.

You should either wait until after you call `getArrayString()` to increment the variable, or subtract 1 from it when calling.

Comment: Thanks, surprised I didn't notice that.